rego rowFilters conflict issues
I have created two rowFilters for same user,same resources with different parameters like city = 'coimbatore', city='Mumbai' when i execute this opa is doing AND by default and i get no rows,but i need an output that contains either of the parameters like it should result rows in coimbatore and mumbai.is there any way without explicity determining OR keyword
i had tried union function and else keyword but im getting errors is there any other way i could get either of the values for same user

What is rowFilters? How have you created them?
